# Rewrite rule help for several languages

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Could anyone help me here with this rewrite rule please?

From this

http://www.SOMEDOMAIN.com/en/somefolder/

To this

http://www.SOMEDOMAIN.com/frontend/somefolder/?idLang=2

From this

http://www.SOMEDOMAIN.com/es/somefolder/

To this

http://www.SOMEDOMAIN.com/frontend/somefolder/?idLang=3

(...)

And for several other languages...where "pt" when the parameter is "idLang=1", "en" when the parameter is "idLang=2",  "es" when the parameter is "idLang=3",  "br" when the parameter is "idLang=5" and "pt" when the parameter is empty.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't a 'please do my work for me' site, it's an 'I've tried this and I can't get it to work, do you know how to make it work' kind of site. So, read up on URL rewriting and try to get it work, if you have a problem then I'm sure someone here can probably help you and you'll get a lot more out of it. If you just want someone to do it for you then I'd suggest one of the sites that brokers developers for bespoke pieces of work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule /en/somefolder/$        /frontend/somefolder/?idLang=2 [L]
RewriteRule /es/somefolder/$        /frontend/somefolder/?idLang=3 [L]
RewriteRule /somefolder/$          /frontend/somefolder/?idLang=1 [L]
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^pt/(.*) frontend/$1?idLang=1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^en/(.*) frontend/$1?idLang=2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^es/(.*) frontend/$1?idLang=3 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^br/(.*) frontend/$1?idLang=5 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule !^frontend/ frontend%{REQUEST_URI}?idLang=1 [QSA,L]
```